# FireStore fromSnapshot vs fromMap for reading DocumentSnapshot?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have been wondering which to use for reading a FireStore snapshot, as I can just use fromSnapshot as `snapshot["fieldName"]` works just fine.

Now, I found an example in Google codelabs at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#10

Is this way the definitive way to go? Eg fromSnapshot, and then use fromMap for snapshot.data? What if I dont use fromMap? What am I losing? And then, I have also seen fromJson instead of fromMap...

```
class Record {
 final String name;
 final int votes;
 final DocumentReference reference;

 Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
     : assert(map['name'] != null),
       assert(map['votes'] != null),
       name = map['name'],
       votes = map['votes'];

 Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
     : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);

 @override
 String toString() => "Record<$name:$votes>";
}
```

Comment: this.fromMap(... now produces

Error: The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
 - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no singular definitive answer for this. Passing a `Map` into your data class ensures that you can also create an object from data that doesn't come from Firestore. But on the other hand, passing a `DocumentSnapshot` ensures that you can make use of any extra metadata in that object if needed (it hardly every is, but still).

I think the approach in the `Record` class is pretty idiomatic: it allows you to use `fromMap` in places (for example unit tests) that don't use Firestore, but then pass in the `DocumentSnapshot` when you're actually getting the data from Firestore.

But as said: none of these approaches is wrong, and picking one is as much personal preference as it is an evolving idiom from the community.