# Can someone explain fromMap() and fromSnapshot() to me

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-pub

Can someone explain the below code to me?I was learning cloud firestore in flutter and i am not able to understand below fromMap conecpt and fromSnapshot conept

```
class Record {
     final String name;
     final int votes;
     final DocumentReference reference;
    
     Record.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
         : assert(map['name'] != null),
           assert(map['votes'] != null),
           name = map['name'],
           votes = map['votes'];
    
     Record.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
         : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);
    
     @override
     String toString() => "Record<$name:$votes>";
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this one could be helpful  ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63439439/firestore-fromsnapshot-vs-frommap-for-reading-documentsnapshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fromMap()` The data which received from API is in JSON format, so it's a key-value pair relationship and for that map is used. And it's used basically to parse the value from the map and assign it to local variables in the model

**Example:**

```
 name = map['name'], 
 votes = map['votes'];
```

Above both variables are accessible from model object instance.

`fromSnapshot():` It's similar to `fromMap()`, the only difference is that it's giving its values in DocumentSnapshot, and call `fromMap()`

Comment: Thank you. this is much clearer to me, now. but can you tell me anything about using clone(:) instead of using the return ..and they could have just used  name = map['name'], 
 votes = map['votes']; but why they are using assert? is it to apply condition ?, where also where can i get to read about these type of coding style?