# How to pass a FireStore DocumentSnapshot to json_serializable fromJson?

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, json-serializable

I am trying to pass a Firebase / Firestore DocumentSnapshot to a json_serializable fromSnapshot, but having some issues. I found some sample code referenced here [FireStore fromSnapshot vs fromMap for reading DocumentSnapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63439439/firestore-fromsnapshot-vs-frommap-for-reading-documentsnapshot) from a now defunct google codelab, but getting an error message `Generative constructors can't redirect to a factory constructor. (Documentation)`

Here is the sample:

```
  MyClass.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromJson(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);

  factory MyClass.fromJson(snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$MyClassFromJson(json);
```

Any tips how to get this to work? Seemed like a simple transformation.